# Sequence of polynomials with rational coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Clearly, the set of all univariate polynomials with rational coefficients is countable. That is, we can enumerate the members, say, as $x_1,x_2, \dots ,x_n, \dots $

How can we find $x_n$ for a given $n$? Is there any formula or algorithm?

Comment: There isn't a unique ordering - take the first $N$ polynomials in any list, and you can permute these in any of $N!$ ways whilst leaving the rest of the order the same. Maybe you want an explicit formula which can be inverted without enumerating the polynomials.

Comment: I know that there isn't unique ordering. Clearly, there are many bijections between the set of positive integers and the set of polynomials with rational coefficients. Is there any formula or algorithm for finding the image of each positive integer in any of such bijections ?

Comment: There is more than one bijection - which one do you mean?

Comment: The [Calkin-Wilf Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree#Breadth_first_traversal) might be of use.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my initial thoughts on making a countable sequence of all univariate polynomials. First, if you have a degree $k$ polynomial and any of the coefficients to an $x^j$ term for $j < k$ is zero, let's represent its coefficient as $\frac{0}{1}$. Also represent any integer coefficients $a$ as $\frac{a}{1}. $Now we can separate all polynomials into a countable number of *bins* that each contain a finite number of polynomials. Let's say that a polynomial is in *bin* $n$ if the sum of all the numerators and denominators of its coefficients (regardless of sign) is $n$. So bin 4 contains the following polynomials:
$$
\pm\frac{3}{1}; \quad \quad 
\pm\frac{1}{1}x\pm\frac{1}{1}; \quad \quad 
\pm\frac{2}{1}x\pm\frac{0}{1};  \quad \quad 
\pm\frac{1}{1}x^2\pm\frac{0}{1}x\pm\frac{0}{1}
$$
This is at least a countable listing of the univariate polynomials, but finding the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ term of this listing is still rather difficult.

Comment: The above is an elegant proof of the countability of polynomials with rational coefficients. I hope there are research papers on finding the $n$-th term of the sequence algorithmically. Any information would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here's a potentially idea. Calculate the number of polynomials in the first few bins (also do this without my condition that integer coefficients be represented as $\frac{a}{1}$). After you have the sequence of these bin sizes, put that sequence in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) and see if it's a known (and maybe calculable) sequence. Then if you need the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ polynomial, you may use this to find out what bin it falls in. Then this problem is only a matter of canonically ordering the polynomials within each bin.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the beginning of a list of all univariate polynomials with rational coefficients:

$$\begin{align}0 = 000000\text{b} &\to 0\\
1 = 000001\text{b} &\to -1\\
2 = 000010\text{b} &\to 1\\
3 = 000011\text{b} &\to -1/2\\
4 = 000100\text{b} &\to -x\\
5 = 000101\text{b} &\to -1 - x\\
6 = 000110\text{b} &\to 1 - x\\
7 = 000111\text{b} &\to -1/2 - x\\
8 = 001000\text{b} &\to 1/2\\
9 = 001001\text{b} &\to -2\\
10 = 001010\text{b} &\to 2\\
11 = 001011\text{b} &\to -1/3\\
12 = 001100\text{b} &\to 1/2 - x\\
13 = 001101\text{b} &\to -2 - x\\
14 = 001110\text{b} &\to 2 - x\\
15 = 001111\text{b} &\to -1/3 - x\\
16 = 010000\text{b} &\to x\\
17 = 010001\text{b} &\to -1 + x\\
18 = 010010\text{b} &\to 1 + x\\
19 = 010011\text{b} &\to -1/2 + x\\
20 = 010100\text{b} &\to -1/2x\\
21 = 010101\text{b} &\to -1 - 1/2x\\
22 = 010110\text{b} &\to 1 - 1/2x\\
23 = 010111\text{b} &\to -1/2 - 1/2x\\
24 = 011000\text{b} &\to 1/2 + x\\
25 = 011001\text{b} &\to -2 + x\\
26 = 011010\text{b} &\to 2 + x\\
27 = 011011\text{b} &\to -1/3 + x\\
28 = 011100\text{b} &\to 1/2 - 1/2x\\
29 = 011101\text{b} &\to -2 - 1/2x\\
30 = 011110\text{b} &\to 2 - 1/2x\\
31 = 011111\text{b} &\to -1/3 - 1/2x\\
32 = 100000\text{b} &\to -x^2\end{align}$$

The bits of the nonnegative index number are allocated to the polynomial coefficients using the triangle sequence $1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \dots$ ([OEIS A002260](https://oeis.org/A002260)), and for each coefficient, the positive and negative coefficients are interleaved: $0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 5, -5, 6, -6, \dots$ ([OEIS A001057](https://oeis.org/A001057)). Without touching the sign thus obtained, unsigned integer-to-rational conversion is done using the [Stern–Brocot tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree), which is closely related to the [Calkin-Wilf tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree).

I wrote [a JavaScript program](http://yehar.com/blog/?p=3593) to do this. The nice thing is that you can start anywhere in the list without having to compute the preceding polynomials. Also the mapping can be inverted quite easily.